# Image src not appearing in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

Building a simple ionic app which connects to an API i've also built. I'm passing some data through to a view and all data is appearing apart fromm the src attribute of an image. If I console.log the data in my controller then the src is there but it doesn't appear in the view - it comes through as a 0 like:

```
<img ng-src="0" src="0">
```

I'm passing it through in my controller like:

```
.controller('VenuesController', ['$state','$scope','$http','Venue', function($state,$scope,$http,Venue){
    $scope.venues = Venue.query();
    $scope.showVenue = function(id){
        $state.go('venues/:id',{id:id});
    };
}])
```

and in the view template itself:

```
<ion-view view-title="Venues">
    <div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="venue in venues" ng-click="showVenue({{venue.id}})" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
          <img ng-src="{{ venue.image-small }}">
          <h2>{{ venue.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ venue.description }}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

The image path is a full external link like `http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?51467` , not sure if i'm missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`venu.image-small` variable has `-` that fails the variable declaration syntax like variable should not have `-`, variable shouldn't start various number, etc.

As your property `image-small` contains an hyphen (`-`) in it, you should use array annotation there to get the value like  `venue['image-small']`

**Markup**

```
<img ng-src="{{ venue['image-small']}}">
```

**Update**

Seems like your `img` source url is different than the you current domain, you need to set the different domain `URL` trusted first using `$sce` service `trustAsResourceUrl` function.

**Markup**

```
<img ng-src="{{ trustSrc(venue['image-small'])}}">
```

**Code**

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

Additionally your ng-click shouldn't use `{{}}` interpolation directive

```
ng-click="showVenue(venue.id)"
```

and then your function should change the implementation of it

```
$scope.showVenue = function(id){
    //removed `venues/:id` and should be replace by its stateName
    $state.go('stateName',{id:id}); 
};
```

Above redirection thing could improved to use `ui-sref` directive like

**Final Markup**

```
<a ng-repeat="venue in venues" ui-sref="stateName({id:id})" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
    <img ng-src="{{ trustSrc(venue['image-small'])}}">
    <h2>{{ venue.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ venue.description }}</p>
</a>
```

Comment: ah thanks, wasn't aware of that. That has changed things but now i'm just getting an empty image tag like `<img>`

Comment: @seengee what should be your `src` url?

Comment: it's data from Faker so it should be something like `http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?51467` - i've tried switching that to a full path with file extension in case that was the issue but still didn't work

Comment: @seengee and what its rendering on the HTML?

Comment: literally just an empty image tag `<img>`

Comment: @seengee then I doubt that your `venue` object `image-small` property has url..could you confirm that first..& then you also need to the changes which I suggested above

Comment: getting `$sce is not defined`

Comment: @seengee you need to add `$sce` to your controller, also make sure you are using `ngSanitize` module in your app.